# Zipping and encryption benchmark comparison

Tags: php, c, encryption, zip, benchmarking

So I'm creating a web application where I need to encrypt / decrypt files, zip them up and send them to the browser.  The site is in php (codeigniter), but the actual file serving component can be in a different language.  I'm wondering if I'd get any kind of speed increase by using something aside from php, like straight c or even shell scripts? Trying to do it right the first time.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Don't worry. The network speed is several orders of magnitude slower than whatever you use to zip / send the files over. Are you going to have **many** simultaneous requests for zipped files?

Comment: This does not really answer your question but perhaps it is a good idea to provide options to enable/disable encryption and compression if that is possible.

Comment: just to mention it ... compressing encrypted data is a futile attempt ... after encryption, your data will look like random bits ...

Comment: Just to confirm what @DarkSquirrel said, if you have files, you can zip them, then encrypt, but doing it the other way round is pointless as you can't compress encrypted files (as there should be no commonality which lets you optimise for compression)

Answer (score 0):

Using FastCGI+C/Python/Whatever_fast could give you massive performance improvements (depending on the specifics of your use case), the reasons for this are:

1. Stateful. PHP has to start a new process on each request and no data
   can be easily reused. With FastCGI you can create huge in-memory caches.
2. More control over what is happenning. Actually
   full control.

Opencaching.pl site had a component written in PHP that was generating PNG images for an overlay of a Google maps widget. Overlay works by rendering the requested images on top of the map so that many geographical points can be labeled without creating DOM objects for each of them. The code consisted of SQL query fetching the points between given coordinates and then drawing them on a canvas using PHP's built-in ImageMagick API. Each view of the map resulted in multiple queries to the PHP script, not mentioning browsing and zooming. The performance was HORRID. Massive memory and CPU usage.

When I rewrote the script to C using FastCGI on Apache as a serving solution, leaving the same logic, same SQL and swapping ImageMagick for SDL, guess what, maassive improvement! And suddenly the biggest bottleneck became the database allowing for even better graphics. SDL is a game graphics library so its performance had to be better! With PHP you are limited to medicore quality libraries.